# Is there another way than presentModalViewController to show a UITabBarController on just part of the screen?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` displaying a number of settings-screens in my app. I want them to be shown on just a part of the screen for layout reasons. In fullscreen, the lists become unreadable (too wide), there are just a few controls per page making the page feel very empty,  and the tabbar buttons are far away from the content (Fitts law).

Using `presentModalViewController` with the `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` style gives me the size I want. I do this on top of an empty background, since in my case it doesn't make sense to display anything behind it. The "real" working area is displayed with another `presentModalViewController` in fullscreen mode on top of it all.

This works but feels like a hack. One problem is, I can't make the background behind the settings dialog move in the transition to fullscreen with the `UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal` style.

**TL;DR**

Can I embed a `UITabBarController` non-fullscreen in another "background"-view? I can't find any information of how I would do this.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I embed a UITabBarController non-fullscreen in another "background"-view? I can't find any information of how I would do this.

Why don't you try it out?

1. Create a container view of the size you want the tab bar controller to have.
2. Create the tab bar controller.
3. `[containerView addSubview:tabBarController.view];`